# Attachment too large to send

Tags: email

How do I delete (get rid of) two emails with attachments too large to send.  Gmail keeps trying to send them and I can't send any other emails.  Be specific.
D. J.

Comment: Are you still at the compose mail screen for these two emails? How large are the attachments?

Comment: @Darlene - did anything I suggested worked ? Are you still having trouble with it (if you are could you describe a little better what is the status of that mail ... i.e. still in compose screen, in drafts, in ... ?)

Answer (score 2):

If you already managed to upload the attachment, go to Drafts, find your email and delete it. If the attachment is not uploaded yet, then just unclick it from the list of files.